# Oracle Driver JDBC Error - WSO2 DS 3 with Oracle 11.2 on Amazon RDS

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, jdbc, wso2, amazon-rds

I tested this URL and with other formats:

*jdbc:oracle:thin:NAME/NAME@//NAME.cbyuxlvomj.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1521/NAME*

With this and others drivers:

http://download.oracle.com/otn/utilities_drivers/jdbc/112/ojdbc6dms.jar

**Configuration with problem**

- WSO2 DataServices 2.7 and 3
- Oracle-se1(11.2.0.2.v7)

**Old configuration that is running**

- WSO2 DataServices 2.7
- Oracle 10

The error that we receive is:

***Error testing connection : Error during executing validation query : Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'***

Please someone can help-me?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please let us know the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Hi Isuru, I added the error on issue.

Comment: Hi Rufo, Thanks for updating the question with the error. It seems that the Oracle JDBC driver class cannot be loaded. Did you use the same jar when connecting with Oracle 10 & Oracle 11?

Comment: Hi Isuru, thanks for feedback. I tested with different jars. I don't know which is correct! Can you help?

Comment: I'm not sure about the URL. What's the correct format?